# Strange CSS behaviour with overflow?

Tags: google-chrome, joomla, mobile-safari, css

I'm having some issues with a Joomla template I'm coding. I think it's because of overflow which I applied to avoid floating issues but not sure at all.

First of all, the page gets a scroll bar on the X axis on Chrome. Working good at IE and Firefox though. The weirdest part is that if you change the window size or just open the Dev tools, it fixes itself... I know I could do something like:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

But I think I shouldn't need it.

Also (and I think it's really related) it's really weird on iOS Mobile Safari and Chrome...

[image: Screenshot]

What's wrong?

http://www.reconstrucciondeaccidentes.es/web/

Comment: Well, this is difficult to debug. All attempts at debugging fix the problem...

Comment: Yep, I tried for more than a day and I finally surrendered... :(

Comment: It's easier for you because you can change the source. You need to narrow down the source of the problem. Firstly, try disabling JavaScript in your browser. If the problem is gone, you know it was caused by JavaScript. Enable JavaScript, and narrow down the scripts to find out which one it is. If the problem is still there with JavaScript disabled, follow the process I just described except with your CSS. Either remove all CSS and add back small parts at a time, or keep all CSS and remove small parts at a time.

Comment: I'd also try removing each block of html, i.e. header, footer etc - one at a time then refresh in Chrome and see if it's a particuular block of html that's causing the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: @thirtydot took your advice and just with the header, the second issue appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Safari assumes a page as being 980px wide. As yours is 990px, the header appears to be sitting outside of the viewport.

You can stop Safari from assuming a 980px page width (which accomodates the majority of sites built for desktop browsers) by putting the following in your :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=990" />`